# Openlayers Overview - disappearing layers

Tags: openlayers-2, layers

when I do this:

```
    var options = {
        autoPan : true,
        size : new OpenLayers.Size(300, 200),
        layers : this.map.layers,
        mapOptions : {
            allOverlays : true
        }
    };
    var ov = new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(options);

    this.map.addControl(ov);
```

my layers are only shown in the overview window. The layers disappear from the main screen.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a clone of the map layer to the overview control rather than the layer itself.

The OpenLayers [overview map example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/overviewmap.html) has a bit more information in the page source:

> A clone of the above layer that we will use as overview for map2.
>     We need to clone jpl before the it gets added to a map, so the
>     clone can have its own maxExtent and maxResolution instead of
>     getting these settings initialized from map1.